# Creating raster with specific value cells of certain size in QGIS

Tags: raster, qgis-3, area, pixel

I have created a raster containing cells with 2 values (1 for content > 0.65 and 0 for all other values). One cell is 25x25 m.

I ran `r.neighbor` to find out which cells are in the neighborhood of the value 1 cells in the range of 1500 m.

Now I want to find out there is an area (or several) where at least 2960 ha connected cells with the value 1 exist.

But since I am  new to QGIS I don't have the slightest idea which tool to use for the task of finding the area of 2960 ha with at least one value 1 cell.

Does anyone have any idea? I use QGIS 3.16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also created a raster containing cells with 2 values (1 and 0); where one cell is 25x25 m. The two big ones areas, situated in right side of following image, have more than 2960 ha.

[image]

So, if you want to search where at least 2960 ha connected cells with the value 1 exist, you can first poligonize with QGIS tool Raster -> Conversion -> Poligonize (Raster to vector). Use 8-conectedness for avoiding connection only by vertex in each cluster. Result was as follow (I edited resulting layer for deleting bottom feature).

[image]

Afterward, in resulting vector layer, I created field **area_ha** by using field calculator ($area/10000). Then, by using "Extract by attribute" Processing tool, with parameters of following image:

[image]

I got below result (red areas have more than 2960 ha):

[image]

Finally, I rasterize above set, Extracted attribute layer, by using following parameters in Raster -> rasterize (Vector to Raster) QGIS tool.

[image]

Result was as expected in resulting raster: only connected cells with at least 2960 ha.

[image]